# MacBook Pro Display Adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, video

Did Apple change the display adapter from MacBook 2006 to MacBook Pro 2010?

I thought they were the same, (similar size) but they actually differ.

Do I have to buy a new adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Output port from early MacBook (and MacBook Pros) was a mini-VGA, later a mini-DVI port and various accessories were available to connect regular size VGA displays. 15" and 17" PowerBooks had full-size DVI outputs as far as I can remember.

Recent MacBook models use a smaller [mini DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort). Apple itself offers different adapters to transform the mini DisplayPort into VGA, DVI, or HDMI. If you need a VGA adapter (like you say in your question tag), you are looking for [this](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB572Z/A). If, on the other hand, you need to connect a DVI display, then [this](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570Z/A?) is what you want.

Comment: Actually, Martin, the Macbook has never had a full-size DVI port. It has had (in order): mini-VGA, mini-DVI and finally mini-DisplayPort.

Comment: @Ben The pro had a full display port at one point, I have one.

Comment: @bmargulies: Full DVI yes - but never full DisplayPort.

Comment: @Che of course, what was I thinking.

Comment: @Ben The MacBook line has never used mini-VGA. That died out with the iBook line. The first non-Pro MacBooks came with mini-DVI,  switching over to Mini DisplayPort with the introduction of the unibody redesign. The first MacBook Pros used a full-sized DVI port until the unibody redesign, when they, too, switched to Mini DisplayPort.

Comment: @Kyle thanks, I remember having a full sized DVI port… but that was a few years ago… in any case, thanks for adding this info. Feel free to modify the answer if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Apple laptops have gone through the following display adapter transitions

- [mini VGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-VGA) and [mini DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DVI) ports were used prior to 2008
- [mini Displayport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort) was used 2009 to 2011
- [Thunderbolt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_%28interface%29) is being used past 2011

The MacBooks never had mini VGA, they started with mini DVI, but earlier Apple laptops such as the iBook used mini VGA. Before they featured mini DisplayPort, early MacBook Pros used a full size DVI port.

Note that a Thunderbolt connector is backwards compatible with mini DisplayPort displays and adapters, and looks the same.  It may seem as though there's been no transition in 2011, but the Thunderbolt port enables new functionality that mini DisplayPort did not have prior to 2011.